# Exponentiation of Pascal's Triangle(in matrix form)

Tags: matrices, algorithms, computer-science, binomial-coefficients, exponentiation

I want to find a pattern in subsequent exponentiations of the pascal triangle shown in the form below
Matrix P[K+1][K+1]:
$$
        \begin{matrix}
        \binom{0}{0} & 0 & 0 & 0\cdots &0\\
        \binom{1}{0} & \binom{1}{1} & 0 & 0\cdots &0 \\
        \binom{2}{0} & \binom{2}{1} & \binom{2}{2} & 0\cdots  &0 \\
        \binom{3}{0} & \binom{3}{1} & \binom{3}{2} & \binom{3}{3}\cdots &0 \\
        \vdots & \vdots  &\vdots  &\vdots\ddots& \vdots\\
        \binom{k}{0} & \binom{k}{1}& \binom{k}{2} & \binom{k}{3}\cdots &\binom{k}{k} \\
\end{matrix}
$$
My motive is to compute $P^N$ in $O(KlogN)$ complexity ,which is definately not possible for any ordinary matrix(which would take $O(K^3logN)$).
But I am pretty much sure it is possible for this special matrix as I have done it in $O(K^2logN)$ but the problem([here](http://www.spoj.com/problems/MOON2/)),which i am solving,suggests
it to be done in $O(KlogN)$,Definately there is a secret which I want to find.
Thanks in Advanced.

Comment: $O(K\log N)$ doesn't seem plausible to me, because you need $O(K^2)$ simply to visit all the elements of the final matrix without even doing any computation. Although if you don't count additions in the complexity, you can use the recursion (sum of two upper elements) in the multiplication step.

Comment: I dont how to close a question,as i got it :)

Comment: Post your own answer below. It may interest other readers to know what you did.

Comment: guys please verify it also as i have deduced it myself..

Answer (score 0):

You can use a binomial expansion and rearrangement to show 
$$(1+N)^{i-j}{i\choose j}=\sum_{n=0}^{i-j} N^{i-j-n}{i-j \choose n} {i\choose j} =\sum_{m=j}^i N^{i-m}{i\choose m} {m\choose j} $$
and then induction to show

$$P^N=\left(\begin{matrix}
        N^{0-0}\binom{0}{0} & 0 & 0 & 0&\cdots &0\\
        N^{1-0}\binom{1}{0} & N^{1-1}\binom{1}{1} & 0 & 0&\cdots &0 \\
        N^{2-0}\binom{2}{0} & N^{2-1}\binom{2}{1} & N^{2-2}\binom{2}{2} & 0&\cdots  &0 \\
        N^{3-0}\binom{3}{0} & N^{3-1}\binom{3}{1} & N^{3-2}\binom{3}{2} & N^{3-3}\binom{3}{3}&\cdots &0 \\
        \vdots & \vdots  &\vdots  &\vdots&\ddots& \vdots\\
        N^{k-0}\binom{k}{0} & N^{k-1}\binom{k}{1}& N^{k-2}\binom{k}{2} & N^{k-3}\binom{k}{3}&\cdots &N^{k-k}\binom{k}{k} \\
\end{matrix}\right)$$

which will give you a fast calculation of any power of $P$ without having to find the intermediate powers.